Cartopy/matplotlib FancyArrowPatch not rendering when using text_adjust on a text layer
I'm trying to render lines from text markers to their original position. The complication is that I'm doing this from Cartopy.
I am using the adjust_text module to move the text labels.
My code looks as follows:-

# Set up the figure and axis

    tiler = OrdnanceSurvey(os_maps_key, layer=kwargs.get('layer', 'Road_3857'))
    tile_crs = tiler.crs

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 5.845))
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, right=0.98, top=0.98, bottom=0.02)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=tile_crs)
    ax.set_extent([bbox[0], bbox[2], bbox[1], bbox[3]], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
    ax.add_image(tiler, zoom_level)

# Iterate through a data frame pts to add markers and text
    
    texts=[]

    for x, y, icon_name, sequence in zip(pts.geometry.x, pts.geometry.y, pts['icon'], pts['sequence']):
      # text labels
      text = ax.text(x, y, int(sequence),
                               bbox={'facecolor': 'none', 'edgecolor': 'none', 'pad': 0},
                               fontsize=12,
                               ha='center', va='center',
                               color='black',
                               transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
      texts.append(text)
      
      # markers
      ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', markersize=5, color='blue', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

# adjust the text labels to remove overlap

    adjust_text(texts,
                ax=ax,
                expand=(4, 2),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='simple', color='blue', lw=1)
                )

The text and markers are rendered but the FancyArrowPatch elements added by adjust_text are not rendered. I've tried passing in the same transform but that has no effect.
I've debugged the code and can see that adjust_text is creating the patches and adding them to ax with ax.add_patch. These appear to have differing start and end coordinates so it looks like they are being created.
How can I get to the bottom of why they are not rendering? Other things I've tried are:-

changing color and lw
setting visible=True
changing zorder=10000

None of these work.
Debugging and looking at transforms there appears to be a mismatch:-
arrowpatch
Out[6]: <matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch at 0x162cc8d10>
arrowpatch.get_transform()
Out[7]: <matplotlib.transforms.IdentityTransform at 0x163439e50>
text.get_transform()
Out[8]: <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform at 0x162c8b190>

But adding transform=ccrs.Geodetic() to the arrowprops gives an error "AttributeError: 'Geodetic' object has no attribute 'quick_vertices_transform'"

Where does adjust_text come from? Can you provide a reproducible code example?

I've edited the question to add a reference to it.

I've found a solution, it is not ideal but the FancyArrowPatch does not deal well with Cartopy transforms passed to it. The solution is to add the arrows outside of adjust_text:-
    original_texts = copy.deepcopy(texts)
    adjust_text(texts,
                ax=ax,
                expand=(4, 2))

    for original, moved in zip(original_texts,texts):
        start_proj = tile_crs.transform_point(*original.get_position(), src_crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
        end_proj = tile_crs.transform_point(*moved.get_position(), src_crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
        arrow = FancyArrowPatch(posA=start_proj, posB=end_proj,
                            arrowstyle='-', mutation_scale=20, lw=0.5, color='blue')

        ax.add_patch(arrow)

